# Isometric Room Generating X, Y Coloring

Tags: javascript, three.js, isometric

I want to generate an isometric room, and I want to color in this style:
[image: How I want]

But my current code gives me this result:
[image: How it is actually]

That's my current code (I don't know, if its the correct way to generate the blocks with this method. Maybee anyone can help me, how its work correctly?

```
for(let iX = 0; iX < 10; iX++) {
    for(let iZ = 0; iZ < 10; iZ++) {
        if(iX % 2 == 0) {
            material = material1;
        } else {
            material = material2;
        }
        
        var box = generateBox(1, 0.1, 1, material);

        box.name = `box-${iX}-${iZ}`;

        box.position.set(iX, box.geometry.parameters.height / 2, iZ);

        room.add(box);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change material style based only on value of `iX` variable. Instead, you should change it based on values of both `iX` and `iZ`  variables like this:

```js
if ((iX + iZ) % 2 === 0) {
  material = material1;
} else {
  material = material2;
}
```

Comment: suggestion :) (!((iX + iZ) % 2)